# Getting Undesired JSON response while using Jackson Provider

Tags: jackson, jersey-2.0, tomcat8, jackson2

I'm currently facing an issue where the response from calling my web service implemented using Jersey 2 framework.

Below the format of the response, I'm getting.

```
{
    "rawType": "java.util.ArrayList",
    "type": {
        "actualTypeArguments": [
            "org.cnt.model.Client"
        ],
        "rawType": "java.util.List",
        "ownerType": null,
        "typeName": "java.util.List<org.cnt.model.Client>"
    },
    "entity": [
        {
            "clientID": 1,
            "clientUID": "CNT123",
            "firstName": "Felimon",
            "lastName":"Adane"
```

.........

EXPECTED FORMAT

```
 callback([{
            "clientID": 1,
            "clientUID": "CNT123",
            "firstName": "Felimon",
            "lastName":"Adane"

   }]
```

TO BE REMOVED

--- The type metadata information added and removing entity wrapper to my actual object.

Any of your suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for responding late after I solved it finally.

I used something like below in my resource methods

return  new JSONWithPadding( **new GenericEntity**>( getAppleList(){}, callback);

instead of

return  new JSONWithPadding(  getAppleList() );

The issue happened when I switched to Jersey 2 which was working fine while I used Jersey 1.

Therefore, It further causes issue on my front end side requiring another parsing from my side. Later I removed the Generic Entity wrapper which gives me the desired result.

Happy Learning!